# Problem adding a background image to a multiple div

Tags: html, css

Wassup guys, I'm trying to do a small website for a school project, and I've encountered a problem with background on a multiple div
So here is my HTML
`

```
        <div class="bloc-1-text">
            <h3>
                
            </h3>
        <p>
            
        </p>
        <div class="bloc-1-img"></div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>`
```

And here my CSS

```
> .promesses{
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.bloc-1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.bloc-1 .bloc-1-img{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%
    background-image: url(image1.jpg);
    position: relative;
}
.bloc-1-text{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bloc-1-text h3{
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is not the entire code, but just the code where is the problematic. If you have anything to specify, just tell me. I'll add it here

Ok so since yesterday, I've tried to go forward a bit. Here is the code:
HTML

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Parti Nationaliste Québécois</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/promesse.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/Logo.png">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="Index.html" class="logo"> <img src="img/Logo.jpg"></a>
        <div class="menu-toggle"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Index.html">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Intention</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chefs</a></li>
                <li><a href="Histoire.html">Histoire</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.paypal.me/Mathislaliberte">Don</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </header>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
          $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('active')
            $('nav').toggleClass('active')
        })
    });
  </script>
    <div class="promesses">
        <div class="bloc-1">
            
            <div class="bloc-1-text">
                <h3>
                    Emploi Assuré
                </h3>
            <p>
                Nous avons pour toi un emploi assuré. Que ce soit dans l'armée ou dans une de nos grandes entreprises dans chacunes de nos région, tu n'auras pas de quoi te plaindre que le plaisir

            </p>
            <div class="bloc-1-img"></div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
`
```

And here is my CSS
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');

```
.promesses{
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bloc-1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;

}

.bloc-1-img{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("img/image1.jpg");
}
.bloc-1-text{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bloc-1-text h3{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bloc-1 .bloc-1-img{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;<<<<<<<----
    background-image: url("image1.jpg");
    position: relative;
}
```

lost ";"

CSS Selector
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: So i added the little ;, nothing change. Still nothing on the side of the image

Comment: u should add explaination of of ur example

Comment: Check where is that photo on your pc.

Comment: Ok so my picture is on the same file as my html file, no other files separating them

Answer (score 0):

delete bloc-1 which is next to block-1-img

and set bloc-1-text to 100vh not 100%

i`ve checked on my pc and it worked

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRns4.png)